# How do I check for duplicates in the same source using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a single source CSV with many duplicate rows. I want to highlight or remove these duplicates. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with Data Flows!

It is quite well explained here by Kromer the great: https://kromerbigdata.com/2019/04/21/use-adf-mapping-data-flows-for-fuzzy-matching-and-dedupe/

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You'll also find those patterns in the ADF pipeline template gallery. Just go to New Pipeline From Template in the ADF UI in your browser and look for these 2 data flow templates:

[image: Distrinct rows and dedupe]